Two cameras on RPi 5 taking the same path
When plugging two RPi cameras v2 in the RPi 5, and using the libcamera-hello --camera 0 -t 5000 command, both that and replacing the 0 with a 1 return the feed from the same camera. Upon checking with libcamera-hello --list-cameras the RPi does detect both cameras, and they also both work when tested separately, so the hardware is not the problem.
I believe that the issue might have something to do with the fact that upon using the --list-cameras both cameras seem to have the exact same path (/base/axi/pcie120000/rp1/i2c@88000/imx219@10), so therefore I suspect that the RPi can only access one camera, since it confuses the two as the same one.
Is this possible, and otherwise how can I fix this problem?
Also, would it be better to use another software, or does it not matter?
